# How to override the plugin in woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I have one plugin "themify-wc-product-filter" in that I want to overwrite "class-wpf-form.php". I have created one child theme also.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to ask the developer if it’s possible to override. Child themes can’t  be used to override any arbitrary file.

Comment: you can look into file and if you understand what exactly it contains and does. then you can override, add or remove its functionality from your functions.php file ( within theme ). You don't have to use child theme for just this purpose.